# Linear Program minimize maximal distance

Tags: linear-programming

Given: Set N = [0,...,n-1], k in N, d_ij >= 0 with d_ii = 0
Task: Find subset C ⊆ N, |C|≤k that minimizes max_i∈N min_j∈C d_ij.

Idea: I define x_i with x_i = 1 if x_i is in C and zero otherwise, constrained by sum(x_i) <= k. Now i want to define w_i, constrained with w_i >= d_ij for one arbitrary j with x_j = 1. Here lies my biggest problem. I can write these things in python but not as a linear program. No matter what i try, i loose linearity or something else in my formulation. If i can do this step, i could define y, constrained by y >= w_i for every i and minimize y. I think, i have a major flaw in my idea but after thinking alot about it, i can t come up with a different approach, Probably because this is th first Lp i have to write. If anyone has any Ideas, as to how i could formulate my Problem as an Lp, i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple MILP-model implemented with MiniZinc:

```
int: nPoints = 4;
    
set of int: POINT = 1..nPoints;
    
array[POINT, POINT] of int: d = [|
    0, 2, 4, 5|
    2, 0, 3, 1|
    1, 4, 0, 4|
    2, 4, 3, 0|];
        
int: k = 2;
int: M = max(d);
    
array[POINT] of var 0..1: x;
array[POINT, POINT] of var int: d_top;
array[POINT, POINT] of var 0..1: r;
array[POINT, POINT] of var int: d_min;
var int: z;
    
% max k points in C
constraint (sum(i in POINT)(x[i]) <= k);
    
% set d_top_ij to d_ij if x_i in C otherwise M 
constraint forall(i, j in POINT)
    (d_top[i,j] = d[i,j]*x[i] + M*(1-x[i]));
    
% exactly one closest point for each point
constraint forall(j in POINT)
    (sum(i in POINT)(r[i,j]) = 1);
    
% d_min_ij = d_top_ij*r_ij (linearize product of continuous variable and binary variable)
constraint forall(i, j in POINT)
    (d_min[i,j] <= d_top[i,j] /\ d_min[i,j] <= M*r[i,j] /\ d_min[i,j] >= 0 /\ d_min[i,j] >= d_top[i,j] - (1-r[i,j])*M);
    
% z is greater than all values in m 
constraint forall(i, j in POINT)(z >= d_min[i,j]);
    
solve
minimize z;
    
output ["obj=\(z)\n"] ++
["x="] ++ [show(x)] ++
["\nd_top=\n"] ++ [show2d(d_top)] ++
["r=\n"] ++ [show2d(r)] ++
["d_min=\n"] ++ [show2d(d_min)];
```

Running gives:

```
obj=1
x=[0, 1, 1, 0]
d_top=
[| 5, 5, 5, 5 |
   2, 0, 3, 1 |
   1, 4, 0, 4 |
   5, 5, 5, 5 |]
r=
[| 0, 0, 0, 0 |
   0, 1, 0, 1 |
   1, 0, 1, 0 |
   0, 0, 0, 0 |]
d_min=
[| 0, 0, 0, 0 |
   0, 0, 0, 1 |
   1, 0, 0, 0 |
   0, 0, 0, 0 |]
```